# Difference between *.intellisense.js and entry in _references.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I've noticed in Visual Studio 2015 that, when creating a new ASP.NET MVC Web project, it automatically adds a `jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js` file. Reading Microsoft's documentation on *.intellisense.js files provided me no clarity, and I'd like to know what this really does. If it adds intellisense into Visual Studio, then how is it different from the `/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" />` entry in _references.js?

Answer (score 0):

The `_references.js` file would give the user intellisense for what's in that file, which would be function names and signatures (parameter names).

The intellisense file contains additional XML comments that Visual Studio can read to give the user more information.  E.g., it can add a `///<summary></summary>` line to summarize the function, a list of `///<param name="">description</param>` to give additional information for parameters, etc.

Since not all people use jQuery in a Visual Studio Environment, the intellisense file was created later after VS added in better support for JavaScript.

Here's an example of creating JavaScript XML comments for VS intellisense: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx